# ASP.NET: Getting System.Web.HttpUnhandledException in production env

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

I am trying to host a website developed in ASP.NET 4 Webforms. While it is running just fine in my Visual Studio 2012, it isn't at remote IIS (version 7.5).

Here is the stacktrace of the exception:-

```
Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Can anybody please help me with this issue?

Comment: Is there any inner exception?

Comment: My log file is providing me this much info only

Comment: are you running it on IISExpress in your local?

Comment: Yes, IISExpress is the default one.

Comment: There can be thousands of reasons why it throws the HttpUnhandledException. The inner exception is vital for solve your question. Can you extend logging to log all inner exceptions recursively?